# How to use Fetch in Jest Javascript Test

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lwc-jest

Setting aside that making HTTP requests during tests isn't the best practice.

I am trying to use `fetch`, but I am getting this error:

> ReferenceError: fetch is not defined

Here is the code:

```
describe('FetchTest', () => {

    it('perform a fetch', async () => {
        // Arrange

        // Act
        const res = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1');
        const result = await res.json();
        console.log(result);

        // Assert
        expect(1).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

1. Why isn't `fetch` available?
2. How do I get `fetch` to work in a `Jest` test so I can make a proper request not a mock request?

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` is a browser API that is used to make HTTP requests, and it is not available in the Node.js environment by default.

Jest is a JavaScript testing framework that runs in a Node.js environment, which is why fetch doesn't work out of the box in Jest tests.
Also jest is used mostly for unit testing and not integration testing.

But you can expose fetch as a global variable and make it work.

Something like this:

```
const MOCK_DATA = {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
        "street": "Kulas Light",
        "suite": "Apt. 556",
        "city": "Gwenborough",
        "zipcode": "92998-3874",
        "geo": {
            "lat": "-37.3159",
            "lng": "81.1496"
        }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
        "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
        "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
        "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
};

global.fetch = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({
    json: () => Promise.resolve(MOCK_DATA)
}));

describe('FetchTest', () => {

    it('perform a fetch', async () => {
        // Arrange

        // Act
        const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1');
        const result = await res.json();
        console.log(result);

        // Assert
        expect(1).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

Comment: How can I make a real request, not a mock request?

Comment: I dont think we can do this in LWC. Its a unit testing framework. Same as Apex, where you cannot hit a real server from test. You can just mock it. If you need to make a real request, you can always use lwc to do that.

Comment: @Robs I'd agree that Nagendra is right--you probably don't want to make real callouts for unit tests. However, if you really wanted to (say, to run a fake express server locally), you could have the fetch method mentioned here call the standard NodeJS [https](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) methods.

Comment: I'm developing against the OpenAI APIs which are nondeterministic, so integration tests are useful